# Cannot load GRASS raster layer with a PyQGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis

I wrote the following script and try to run it in QGIS Python console.
I use it to load data from a GRASS repository.

This script used to run fine with QGIS 3.16.4 and GRASS GIS 7.8.6dev
But it doesn't work any more a new installation: Debian bullseye[11], QGIS 3.24.1-Tisler 'Tisler' (5709b82461), GRASS GIS 7.8.5

There is no error message in the console.

Is there something wrong in the script ?

The script:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer,QgsRasterLayer,QgsDataSourceUri,QgsProject,QgsLineSymbol
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo 
import os, glob


raster_directory="/home/donnees/grassdata/grass7data/surfaces/forgenius/cellhd"
filtre_images="*.tif"

# create project instance
proj = QgsProject.instance()

img_dir=raster_directory
os.chdir(img_dir)

for file in glob.glob(filtre_images):
    iname, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    nomGroupe = "g_" + iname

    # adding a group
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    surfaceGroup = root.addGroup(nomGroupe)

    # adding raster layer for this group (grass repository
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(os.path.join(img_dir,file))
    path = fileInfo.filePath()
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    layer = QgsRasterLayer(path, baseName)
    dimLayerY=layer.height()
    layer_pointer=proj.addMapLayer(layer,False) 
    surfaceGroup.addLayer(layer_pointer)
```

Comment: We have a One question per Question policy here. Specifying a bullet-list of questions generally results in closure.

Comment: Did you check the Grass GIS provider and GRASS 7 in the plugin menu ?

Comment: `dir` is a [function name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) in Python, I would recommend using a different variable name. Also, using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#:~:text=os.path.join(path%2C%20*paths)%C2%B6) is more reliable than concatenating filepaths with `+`. Moreover, you have syntax errors in your posted code: line 2 should not be a new line and `import os, glob` should be on a new line.

Comment: Following suggestions, I updated the script, but it doesn't work. As explained, the script  used to work fine with previous version of qgis 3.16. It doesn't work with giq 3.24 nor 3.26.